# Determine the number of triples given..

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let n ≥ 1 be an integer, and let X and Y be two disjoint sets, each consisting of n elements. An ordered triple (A,B,C) of sets is called *iconic*, if

A⊆X,B⊆Y,C⊆B, and|A|+|B|=n

Let k be an integer with 0 ≤ k ≤ n. Determine the number of *iconic* triples (A,B,C)
for which |A| = k.

Let k be an integer with 0 ≤ k ≤ n. Determine the number of *iconic* triples (A,B,C)
for which |C| = k.

Use the above two results to prove that

[Click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DajlB.png)

Comment: You have to provide some effort on solving this,   do you have an idea how to start?

Comment: I'm gonna be honest, I have no clue. Having a lot of trouble grasping this whole concept.

Comment: The results are the expresions in the given sums, and both sums represent all possible iconic triples. Thats why are equal. You can try to conlude how they got to these expressions

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov I still don't understand this :/

Answer (score 0):

For the first case you pick k elements from X to make A so it is $n \choose k$ possibilities.

Then you pick n-k elements from Y to make B, which is again $n \choose k$

Then you pick one of possible subsets of B, that is $2^{n-k}$, like giving each element 0 or 1 according if they are in C or not

So in total it is $({n \choose k})^2 2^{n-k}$

For second case you pick k elements from Y to make C, and from the rest of X U Y \ C you pick n-k to form A U B \ C, that is $2n-k \choose n-k$.

So in total ${n \choose k} {2n-k \choose n-k} $

If you sum the formulas for all possible k you will get all possible iconic triples for both cases, thats why the given equation stands